# Windows Phone Universal App error calling async function on load

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, asynchronous, async-await, win-universal-app

Hi i have this code on windows phone main window code

```
namespace Balcão_Virutal_UBI
{

    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public bool hasloggin = false;
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;

            fetchInfo();
        }

        private async void fetchInfo()
        {
            FetchData fd = new FetchData();
            Dictionary<string, string> schedule = await fd.GetSchedule_HC("12", "ui");
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in schedule)
            {
                horario.Items.Add(entry.Key + "|" + entry.Value);
            }
        }


        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {

            // TODO: Prepare page for display here.

            // TODO: If your application contains multiple pages, ensure that you are
            // handling the hardware Back button by registering for the
            // Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed event.
            // If you are using the NavigationHelper provided by some templates,
            // this event is handled for you.
        }
    }
}
```

and the function being called

HtmlWeb htmlW;

```
    public async Task<Dictionary<string, string>> GetSchedule_HC(string day, string week)
    {
        string year = "21"; //get from settings
        string semestre = "S1"; //get from settings
        string ciclo = "1"; //get from settings
        string course = "1408"; //get from settings
        string url = "https://academicos.ubi.pt/online/horarios.aspx?p=a";
        string cicleY = "1"; //get from settings

        htmlW = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlDocument htmlDoc = await htmlW.LoadFromWebAsync(url);
        IEnumerable<HtmlNode> selectElm = from selectNode in htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants()
                                          where selectNode.Name == "select" && selectNode.Attributes["id"].Value == "ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlAnoLect"
                                          select selectNode;
        Dictionary<string, string> rtnval = new Dictionary<string,string>();
        foreach (HtmlNode node in selectElm)
        {
            rtnval.Add(node.Attributes["value"].Value, node.InnerText);
        }
        return rtnval;
    }
```

And I get this error on launching the app global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();

I had messagebox with await and switched to a listbox, but the problem was the same... I tryed to find solution but I was unable to

Comment: Hard to tell how your code should be fixed without info about detailed error message or the line that actually throwing the exception. So, just a suggestion, you can use `GetAttributeValue()` to get an attribute value safely : `selectNode.GetAttributeValue("id","") == "ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlAnoLect"`. This way you won't get exception in case current `HtmlNode` doesn't have `id` attribute

Comment: Used your code fix, still nothing, any idea how can I get error information? because de code seems fine. Unless the foreach as some problem... I'm trying to get the options of a select

Comment: Put breakpoint at the beginning of your async method, run the project in debug mode and step line by line after the execution hit the breakpoint. See if any exception thrown in that method

Comment: Did that... And It throw me this `if (!rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments))
                {
                    throw new Exception("Failed to create initial page");
                }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After mutch testing with breakpoints and StepByStep debugging I was able to find out the problems...
Thx Jeff Sanders, that tip helped to have the UI fully loaded before loading the content and the rest of the solution was parcially given to me by a user in Portugal a Programar forum.
Here is the fix

```
public async Task<Dictionary<string,string>> GetSchedule_HC(string day, string week)
        {
            string year = "21"; //get from settings
            string semestre = "S1"; //get from settings
            string ciclo = "1"; //get from settings
            string course = "1408"; //get from settings
            string url = "https://academicos.ubi.pt/online/horarios.aspx?p=a";
            string cicleY = "1"; //get from settings


            string htmlPage;
            using(var wp = new HttpClient())
            {
                htmlPage = await wp.GetStringAsync(new Uri(url));
            }

            HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
            htmlDoc.LoadHtml(htmlPage);
            Dictionary<string, string> rtnval = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            HtmlNodeCollection selectNode = htmlDoc.GetElementbyId("ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlAnoLect").ChildNodes;

            foreach (HtmlNode optNode in selectNode)
            {                
                if (optNode.Name == "option")
                {
                    string txt = optNode.NextSibling.InnerText;
                    string val = optNode.Attributes["value"].Value;
                    rtnval.Add(val,txt);
                }
            }



            return rtnval;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The visual tree is not constructed until the Page Loaded event is fired.  Try moving your fetchInfo() function into the Loaded event.

Comment: Tryed that... It does not send me to this `if (!rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments))                 {                     throw new Exception("Failed to create initial page");                 }`, but does give me this error global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();

Comment: You should be able to inspect the arguments passed to that and see what the exception is.  Can you inspect that in the debugger?